# Unpivot Multiple Columns with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

Need to unpivot multiple columns which list options and option prices. Example starting dataset can be created with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable (
ID int,
OptionA nvarchar(25),
OptionACost decimal(16,4), 
OptionB nvarchar(25),
OptionBCost decimal(16,4), 
OptionC nvarchar(25),
OptionCCost decimal(16,4) )

INSERT INTO testtable (ID, OptionA, OptionACost, OptionB, OptionBCost, 
OptionC, OptionCCost) 

VALUES
    ('1', 'Red Paint', '11.98', 'Leather Trim', '20.00', 'Matte Finish', '5.66'),
    ('2', 'Blue Paint', '13.48', 'Suede Trim', '16.00', 'Gloss Finish', '3.82'),
    ('3', 'Black Paint', '10.00', 'Leather Trim', '20.00', 'Matte Finish', '5.66'),
    ('4', 'Red Paint', '11.98', 'No Trim', '0.00', 'Matte Finish', '5.66');
```

My ideal result sample dataset is created with this code:

```
CREATE TABLE testtableresult (
ID int,
OptionName nvarchar(25),
OptionCost decimal(16,4))

INSERT INTO testtable2 (ID, OptionName, OptionCost)
VALUES
    ('1', 'Red Paint', '11.98'),
    ('2', 'Blue Paint', '13.48'),
    ('3', 'Black Paint', '10.00'),
    ('4', 'Red Paint', '11.98')
    ('1', 'Leather Trim', '20.00'),
    ('2', 'Suede Trim', '16.00'),
    ('3', 'Leather Trim', '20.00'),
    ('4', 'No Trim', '0.00')
    ('1', 'Matte Finish', '5.66'),
    ('2', 'Suede Trim', '3.88'),
    ('3', 'Matte Finish', '5.66'),
    ('4', 'Matte Finish', '5.66');
```

Comment: Added the tag, sql server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server has `APPLY` operator  (i.e. `CROSS APPLY`) which could do that what you want something similar as `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT a.* FROM #testtable t
CROSS APPLY (
    VALUES (ID, OptionA, OptionACost, 1), (ID,OptionB, OptionBCost, 2),
           (ID, OptionC, OptionCCost, 3)
)a(Id, Name, Cost, ids)
ORDER BY a.ids, a.id
```

Comment: This works thank you! The only hard thing here is that i have 100+ options but I don't see a better way.

Comment: @SanomaJean, If you have 100+ of options then you can take Yogesh's approach and create it dynamically. see solution below.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT ID, OptionA AS OptionName, 
>            CAST(OptionACost as decimal(10,2)) AS OptionCost 
> FROM testtable
> UNION ALL
> SELECT ID, OptionB AS OptionName, 
>            CAST(OptionBCost as decimal(10,2)) AS OptionCost 
> FROM testtable
> UNION ALL
> SELECT ID, OptionC AS OptionName, 
>            CAST(OptionCCost as decimal(10,2)) AS OptionCost 
> FROM testtable
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | OptionName   | OptionCost
> -: | :----------- | :---------
>  1 | Red Paint    | 11.98     
>  2 | Blue Paint   | 13.48     
>  3 | Black Paint  | 10.00     
>  4 | Red Paint    | 11.98     
>  1 | Leather Trim | 20.00     
>  2 | Suede Trim   | 16.00     
>  3 | Leather Trim | 20.00     
>  4 | No Trim      | 0.00      
>  1 | Matte Finish | 5.66      
>  2 | Gloss Finish | 3.82      
>  3 | Matte Finish | 5.66      
>  4 | Matte Finish | 5.66
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=21abee23e0f6849d0a1875cea21406f0)*

Comment: This is great, the only issue is there are 100+ options so I don't think this is feasible for a big scale :(

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [Yogesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5529445/yogesh-sharma) solution, here is the code to dynamically create the multiple `CROSS APPLY`

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZFZSM50853)

**NOTE**
**The main assumption is that your columns in the testtable are called "Option<>"
and "Option<>Cost" in order to create the grouping correctly**

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Cols') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Cols
    ;WITH Cols as
    (
        SELECT COLUMN_NAME , FIRST_VALUE(COLUMN_NAME) OVER (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) MainCol
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'testtable'
    )
    SELECT *
    INTO #Cols
    FROM Cols
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME !=MainCol


    DECLARE @ColsOptions NVARCHAR(MAX)= ''
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX)= ''
    ;WITH Pvt as 
        (
        SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MainCol ORDER BY SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,LEN('Option')+1, 1)) Grp
        FROM #Cols
        )
    , InternalPvt AS 
        (
        SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY Grp) InternalGrp
        FROM Pvt
        )
    , CrossApply as 
    (
     SELECT MAX(MainCol) MainCol,
            MAX(CASE WHEN  InternalGrp = 1 THEN COLUMN_NAME END) [Option],
            MAX(CASE WHEN  InternalGrp = 2 THEN COLUMN_NAME END) OptionCost,
            Grp
     FROM InternalPvt   
     GROUP BY Grp
     )

     SELECT @ColsOptions += '('+MainCol+','+[Option]+','+OptionCost+','+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10),Grp) +'),'+CHAR(10) 
     FROM CrossApply
     SET @ColsOptions = SUBSTRING(@ColsOptions,0,LEN(@ColsOptions) - 1 )

     SET @sql = 
    'SELECT a.*
     FROM testtable t
     CROSS APPLY (
                VALUES '+@ColsOptions+'
                ) a(Id, Name, Cost, ids)
     ORDER BY a.ids, a.id'

    exec sp_executesql @Sql
```